# Is it possible to use Laravel Horizon installed within one module to monitor queues in another module, both of which are using the same Redis?

Tags: laravel, redis, multiple-projects, laravel-jobs, laravel-horizon

iam new to Redis and Horizon

i have two laravel projects hosted in same server, which are using same database and same redis service.

Let's say the projects are `X` and `Y`.

I have configured Laravel Horizon in `X` and its running fine. I'm able to monitor all the queues running inside this. running the worker inside in `X`

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=Xqueue,Yqueue
```

in the same way there are some queues inside `Y`. So i want to know that is it possible to monitor the queues in `Y` using the horizon that is configured in `X`

NOTE: using same redis link and configuration in both

When i run the command *php artisan queue:work --queue=Xqueue,Yqueue* in `X`. and dispatch a job in `Y` by running *dispatch(new TestJob())->onQueue('Yqueue');* .

The job was failing all the time.

Iam not sure if it possible, or this is the correct way.

So what i want know is is it possible queues in `X` and `Y` should be monitored by the horizon configured in `X`. or what i have to do ?

Thank you for the help